# Why I get error on multiple dir-pagination in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, dirpagination

I have problem with dir-pagination. I have multiple tables and I added to same dir-pagination attribute 'id'.

```
<tr dir-paginate="call in ( filterCalls = (calllRecords |  filter :searchInput 
                                            | filter:{typeCall:cats || undefined} | filter:{created_by:createdBySort} 
                                            | filter:{deleted: myFilter(cats)} |
                                            orderBy:orderByField:reverseSortArr[orderByField] |
                                             itemsPerPage: itemsPerPage))" pagination-id="callPagin">
```

And I have this directive

```
<dir-pagination-controls boundary-links="true" pagination-id="callPagin" on-page-change="pageChangeHandelr(newPageNumber)"></dir-pagination-controls>
```

And I got this error:

```
Syntax Error: Token ':' is an unexpected token at column...
```

Why this happen?

**EDIT:**
Angular controller:

```
$scope.getCallsRecords = function(){

$http({
        method : "POST",
        url    : "/getCallRecords",
    }).success(function(res){
        $scope.calllRecords = res;
    });
}

$scope.getCallsRecords();

$scope.getAssignments = function(deleted = 0){

    $http({
        method : "POST",
        url    : "/getAssignment"
    }).success(function(res){
        $scope.assignments = res;

    });
}

$scope.getAssignments();
```

Comment: try to use like this `orderBy:{orderByField:reverseSortArr[orderByField]}`

Comment: Try that, still doesn't work

Comment: could you please specify the exact question? what exactly you want to do?

Comment: I want to create pagination using angular. But when I added the pagination-id attribute it throw an error and the data doesn't load.

Comment: are there more than one data source ,you are using to bind the table?

Comment: yes, I am using 2 data source called in angular

Comment: this will be more complicated by using two data sources,you can put those two data sources into one , and use a single data source

Comment: but this doesn't solves my problem

Comment: could you please share your controller code?

Comment: I have edit my question

Comment: what if you make an empty and push both of your array into it.so that you will have a single data source

Comment: I need those two cause I have two tables

Comment: than why don't you use one data source per table

Comment: Thats what I am doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it. I changed the dir-paginate attribute in tr tag. I removed the `fillterCalls` so now this looke like this

```
<tr dir-paginate="call in calllRecords |  filter :searchInput 
                                       | filter:{typeCall:cats || undefined} 
                                       | filter:{created_by:createdBySort} 
                                       | filter:{deleted: myFilter(cats)} |  
                                       orderBy: orderByField : reverseSortArr[orderByField] 
                                       | itemsPerPage: itemsPerPage" 
                                       pagination-id="callPagin">
```